# Is the 'self' optional here on line 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

Is self optional here?

```
class Anagram
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def match(words)
    words.select do |word|
      word.split("").sort == self.name.split("").sort
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Also, what is line 10? There is only one line in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyword `self` refers to class instance. So, calling attribute name by default called on current object with which it is called. So, it's **optional**.

Comment: as he is using `attr_reader :name` in the class self is optional.

Comment: It is very likely that `self` here does refer to an instance of `Anagram`. But it can't be guaranteed. We don't know what `words` is, and what its `select` does. Maybe it changes `self`? In ruby you never know. :shrug:. Regardless of that, in absence of local variable `name`, `self` is indeed optional.

Comment: Thanks much all. It's now quite clear.